# Handle screen orientation in android?

Tags: android

me new to android developments,
tell me how to handle screen orientation in android.
I have done android:configchanges in manifeast file,also override the onConfigurationChanged method.

But something went wrong.
if any1 is having demo app so that i can learn .

thnx for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.androidguys.com/tag/android-rotation/) series of article might prove useful.

Comment: @Sumant: if you think this answer was useful, vote up. If it answered your question, accept it.